# Update variable in a JS Static Resource

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources, configuration

I have a js library uploaded as a static resource that I am using in my VF page. This library has a "config" object which contains server info etc.

The problem is that I need to update the "config" object from my VF page as per my requirement, please let me know what are the ways that I can achieve this?

One way that I have tried is that, If I use another js file containing "config" object as a static resource in my VF page, it works fine.

But my goal is to update this "config" object from VF page dynamically.

Comment: As long as the config object is accessible through a global variable (e.g. something attached to `window`), you can access it dynamically via `window.config` or the like. Without seeing some sample code, it'd be hard to say much more than this.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes with window.config it is accessible and I am able to update it as well. Earlier I was trying it to access with just config. Please post it as an answer so I may accept that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, each imported file is isolated by default. However, you can access any global variable, one attached to `window`, to work with data and methods from that file. In your case, you can use `window.config` to access the configuration from Visualforce.